# How to sort members in VSCode (java)?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In Eclipse there is an option that sorts the code automatically `source > sort members > all members`.

[image]

Be careful not to be confused with refactoring. I am not looking to indent the code but to reorder the methods.

Does anyone know how I can do the same in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported at the moment.
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2274